# Parameterized tests with JUnitParamsRunner for Mockito.verify() of different methods

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, parameterized-unit-test

So, I have a method that takes an Object parameter and depending on its value invokes different methods (I use just if statements instead of switch).

```
public class ClassToTest {

    public void methodToTest(String input) {
        if (input.equals("A")) {
            ServiceClass.methodA();
        }
        if (input.contentEquals("B")) {
            ServiceClass.methodB();
        }
        if (input.contentEquals("C")) {
            ServiceClass.methodC();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ServiceClass {

    public static void methodA() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    public static void methodB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    public static void methodC() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

I know that JUnitParamsRunner simplifies writing of parameterized tests and I know about Mockito.verify() to check if specific method was invoked. But in my case is it possible to make a parameterized test of different inputs and check if a respective method have been called? Or is it that for verify() I need to write separate tests for each scenario.

Comment: As static method should interact with some external resource (in your example it is `System.out`), I would rather try to verify this interaction instead of method call. Have you tried to reassign `System.out` and assert it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to verify the static method in your ServiceClass. In that case `Mockito` can't help you, as its not able to deal with static methods. You might want to use `PowerMockito` for this.

Here an example of how this would look like.
Tested with `PowerMockito 2.0.4` and the mockito2 api.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServiceClass.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class ParamsTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters({"A", "B", "C"})
    public void test(String input) throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceClass.class);

        new ClassToTest().methodToTest(input);

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(ServiceClass.class);

        switch (input) {
            case "A":
                ServiceClass.methodA();
                break;
            case "B":
                ServiceClass.methodB();
                break;
            case "C":
                ServiceClass.methodC();
                break;
            default:
                Assert.fail();
        }
    }
}
```

The verification part looks rather ugly, so I am not sure whether that is worth doing it.

It should be possible to pass the verification part as another argument to the test as well, but that doesn't really make it better.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but you use switch inside the test method. However, what I wanted is a parameterized tests where the input is the object's value, while the expected value/event is invocation of specific method. However, I think I have to write separate tests for each method invocation: test1_methodA, test2_methodB etc.

Comment: Consider rereading the last sentence. While its technical possible to pass the verification part as parameter (like you would pass a dynamic result), it does not help the readability of the test. I agree that going for separate tests seems to be the best approach for these kind of tests.